# Problems deploying MVC 4 application to website already hosting classic ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am in the introductory steps of teaching myself ASP.Net MVC 4 with the intent of converting old Classic ASP code. So, I have made a simple Hello World application in MVC4 and want to deploy it to our development server. The development server currently mirrors our production environment. The production environment hosts a bevy of Classic ASP pages, hosted in the "web" directory.

I have used the publish button in VS to upload the hello world page to the dev server, dropping it into the "web" directory. So, within the "web" directory, there are 2 new folders /bin and /Views. The actual page I created resides within the /Views/Home directory.

After the code was uploaded I pulled up IE and attempted to view the hello world page by navigating to localhost/views/home/index.cshtml and I received a 404 error.

I then pulled up the directory listing in IIS and navigated down to the "home" directory. I right-clicked this folder and selected "convert to application".

At this point I was able to see my hello world page by directing IE to the root localhost. However, after removing the "home" directory from the application list (essentially undoing the "convert to application"), the hello world page still shows when I pull up the root directory in IE. I've checked the default pages list in IIS, and my Classic ASP homepage still lists as the first selection.

So, I'm kinda confused on how to make MVC and classic asp play nicely together. First and foremost, I'd like to get my dev server pointing back to it's original default page so that it matches the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separated directory for your MVC4 application beside the web directory. After this create a new web application inside the IIS console and point the source directory to your new application directory (set the new application's AppPool to integrated). Everything should work fine.

Comment: Will only add that if you're using IIS 6 you should add a wildcard mapping to %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll so you can use the extensionless urls.  And make sure to uncheck "verify the file exists"

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure how I was going to differentiate between the 2 sites but when I created the new site to test the mvc application I just assigned it to port 81 and was able to view it via localhost:81. Thanks again!